# How to import RTL SCSS in SASS file Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I’m using Sass to customize Bootstrap 5. I want to **enable RTL support** for my project, but I’m not sure how to import the `bootstrap.rtl.scss` file and use the mixins from Bootstrap.
I have this line in my custom Sass file: `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`. How can I change it to import the RTL version of Bootstrap and use the mixins like `@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {...}` or `@extend .container`?

for example:

```html
<html lang='fa' dir='rtl'>
...
</html>
```

```scss
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
.newsletter {
    @extend .input-group, .shadow;
}
...
```

but change direction to RTL, objects are to right but not border-radius set correctly!:
[image: bootstrap5 component in rtl version]

Comment: There is no import required. Just add the `dir="rtl"` attribute to your `<HTML>` tag. Additionally you could use this documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I added this, but it does not work correctly! For example, ```border-radius``` in ```input-group``` does not work, or ```offset-md-4 …```

Comment: Then please post a [repro] and define "not work"